# Provisioning Profiles Not Found inside xamarin studio, its found in xcode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, provisioning

I Have problem in my xamarin.forms app I need Publish my App to App Store and create Provisioning Profiles and install it to my pc.

Now when i try to select Provisioning profile its showing "No matching profile found".

When i have tried same with Xcode its working fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKUzv.png)

And When i have add my Apple developer account in "Apple Developer Accounts" in visual studio for mac then it will show the list of my all Provisioning profiles.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyvUt.png)

So please help me for fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Delete the Provisioning Profiles and create a new one.And here is a similar issue that you can refer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/128131/error-could-not-find-any-available-provisioning-profiles-for-ios.

Comment: I have Delete the Provisioning Profiles and create a new one then also Provisioning not found.

Thanks you.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/357083#Comment_357083 refer to this similar issue.